# Convert list of characters into a list with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

If a user inputs a string `"Hello world"`
how can i get an output list to look like `["Hello", "world"]`
instead of `['H','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d']`
Whats an efficient way to do this?

I used a for loop, and omitted the whitespace but my output does not include the last character

```
def reverse_string(x):
    reversed_list= []
    temp_string = ""
    count= 0
    for i in x:
        if i == " " or i == x[-1]:
            reversed_list.insert(count, temp_string)
            temp_string = ""
            count+=1
            continue
        temp_string += i
```

my output: `['Hello', 'worl']`

sorry if this is a repost

Comment: `x.split()` can't get more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()`.

Example.

```
x = "Hello world"
x.split( )
```

Please add any character you want to split at if you want to split on whitespace use like this

```
x.split(" ")
```